# Deploying on jboss using getCurrentSession

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I have implemented DAO's based on [Link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects) in the HibernateDAOFactory class, there is a method

```
protected Session getCurrentSession() {
     return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
}
```

To implement the same i have made the hibernate.cfg.xml changes as described in the below articles [Here 1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/htmlarchitecture.html#architecture-current-session)
[HERE 2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-j2ee-currentsession)

```
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property><br/>
    <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

While deploying it on jboss i get the following errors

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: could not register synchronization
```

I even set the property

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
```

but i got the following error.

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction

 at org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:88)

 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)
```

Am i missing something out here??
My jboss version is 4.2.3 and hibernate version is 3.3.1 and using Java 7.

Comment: You how you manage transactions? Do you have spring or do it manually?

Comment: public static Session getCurrentSession()
    {
         Session currentSession = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
         if (!currentSession.getTransaction().isActive())
         {
               currentSession.getTransaction().begin();
         }
         return currentSession;
 }

Comment: I don't use spring framework.
Let me know if i am wrong.Jboss should automatically handle the transaction via this property.<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>

Comment: You seem to be running inside JBoss, which has a JTA transaction manager. You shouldn't start transaction yourself this way. You should use EJBs and declarative transaction management.

Comment: Just to pin-point the exact problem.Whenever i am trying to fetch the current session `getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` at that point i face the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet any reference/link you can point me to for the same...

Comment: No, not really. The official JEE6 tutorial maybe? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnblr.html

Comment: `<property name="connection.datasource">TestDS</property> <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>`

Comment: You're using JBoss 4.2.3 (which is ancient), Hibernate 3.3.1 (which is also ancient), and Java 7 (which is bleeding edge)? Is that version of JBoss certified on Java 7? Do you have a particular reason to use that combination of versions? If you could at least use a modern Hibernate, you'd be doing yourself a huge favour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for thread based session management I removed the `transaction.factory_class` and `manager_lookup_class` property from my hibernate.cfg.xml and it worked like a charm.

But for jta based session management, I am still getting the same error.